# PostgreSQL datatype pointless if ARRAY?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

When creating a column as `bitint[]` in example...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name bigint[];
```

...and then retrieving the column datatype...

```
SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='table_name' AND column_name='column_name';
```

...the query returns a value of `ARRAY` for each type set to an array.

Since the type always returns `ARRAY` does that make the initial datatype when using `ALTER` a pointless alias of `ARRAY`?

...or...

Should we simply use the following instead?

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name ARRAY;
```

Using...

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='table_name' AND column_name='column_name';
```

...seems to reveal nothing that suggests the column is a `BIGINT` type in any manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a pointless alias for ARRAY. The details are just in a different view: "information_schema"."element_types".

[The documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-element-types.html) includes this query, which joins "columns" and "element_types".

```
SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type, e.data_type AS element_type
FROM information_schema.columns c LEFT JOIN information_schema.element_types e
     ON ((c.table_catalog, c.table_schema, c.table_name, 'TABLE', c.dtd_identifier)
       = (e.object_catalog, e.object_schema, e.object_name, e.object_type, e.collection_type_identifier))
WHERE c.table_schema = '...' AND c.table_name = '...'
ORDER BY c.ordinal_position;
```

In your original query, you ignored the schema, probably because you know all your tables are in the "public" schema. But in practice, you need to include the schema in the WHERE clause. You can have tables and columns with the same name in different schemas.